# Eclipse Not stopping at break point :Remote Java Debugging (done locally)

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, tomcat

I have defined a `setenv.bat` in the tomcat 9 and its contents are as follows:

```
CATALINA_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"
JPDA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"
```

In the Eclipse I have setup a new Remote Java Application by right clicking my project and setting host as `localhost`, port as `8000`. 
Didn't check `allow termination of remote VM`.

*Here are few more steps I am following:*

I stopped the tomcat server from the `Servers tab` of Eclipse.

I started from command line the tomcat using `catalina jpda start`. The server starts successfully in a separately command window.

I put a break point in the code in eclipse and run my webservice like the following in POSTMAN:

`http://localhost:8080/myProject/search?id=1234`

Nothing happens in Eclipse. Basically the eclipse isn't starting in Debug Mode it looks like. Any additional setting I need to do for 
making it work? I remember a Debug window used to open when I did this few years back and not able to recall now and figure out what mistake I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you edit your setenv.bat as follows,

```
rem CATALINA_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"
rem JPDA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"
set JPDA_SUSPEND=y
```

then can you attache the debugger?

Comment: I tried doing this and after running `catalina jpda start` in the tomcat window I saw `Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000` and nothing else for long time. Could you tell me the reason behind suggesting this approach? Thanks

Comment: setenv.sh (on Linux) does not need `export` command but setenv.bat (on Windows) needs `set` command. If you can see `Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000`, then you can also attatch debugger. If you cannot attatch debugger at this time, your eclipse setting or position of break point is wrong. * I should have answered `set JPDA_SUSPEND=n`.

Answer (score 0):

Some missing links here.

Before you started from the command prompt, did you ensure that your web-app is deployed?
When deploying an app via the Eclipse Servers plugin, you can choose three options related to the deployment. Now, for the server you stopped from eclipse, which one of these options did you choose?[image: See the Server Locations side on the left side]

Your attempt to debug from command prompt and attaching a remote debugger will only work if you chose to deploy in the tomcat root directory. Other two modes will NOT change your tomcat installation directory by deploying your web app there and hence your URL may not actually be invoking any classes (and will return a 404). So of you set up a debug point in your classes assuming they are deployed, then please recheck.

Edit: Since the Catalina shell file is being changed, the inference while composing this answer has been that you were using the Tomcat installation directory.

[Edit] In the wake of the comments below. The following two options would help you go thru:

1. Change the deployment to the actual Tomcat installation and then as you mentioned above, attach the debugger
2. Use the Eclipse WTP Debug on Server option.

Comment: Thanks. I have exactly same scenario at my end like the screenshot you mentioned. So the server I am referring to from the eclipse is the 
same where I am trying to start the server in debug mode using `cataline jpda start`. Here is the screenshot of the image : 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQBkU.png

Comment: So when you say three options , I am trying to understand what other thing I am missing. As far as 
 project deployment is concerned, when I right click on my server (from the Servers tab) and click on `Add and Remove`, I can see my project 
 in the `Configured` section. This is how the web-app gets deployed when I start the server from Eclipse. Please correct me if you were asking 
 something different. Thanks again.

Comment: For comment 1: If your server is not on actual installation, then modifying the batch or shell file in the installation would not work would it?

Comment 2. When you right click and start the server, the libraries from the tomcat installation are referred to, but eclipse WTP feigns a deployment by placing files in a separate folder. For the specific location, look closely at your elipse console. In your workspace's meta folder, a plugin folder with this name can be found. That is where all the right click and deploy files are located. Tomcat is being started by eclipseWTP using an APi call.

Comment: Eclipse WTP link for Run on server: http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/wst/components/server/runOnServer.html